# Sed regex expression?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I was wondering if somebody could help me with this `sed` regex expression.

I will put the whole code:

```
for w in ./tmp/horse_F3.csfasta; do
    sed -n '/^>/!{H;$!b};s/$/ /;x;1b;s/\n//g;p'  ${w} > ${w}.flat
done
```

Comment: You seem to be using fasta format files.  What is your expected input & expected output?  One or two blocks (>header + data block) of the file is fine.

Comment: Are you asking us to edit it? Or are you asking us to tell you what it does?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what to expect... I am studying and script that formats csfasta files to flat files (whatever that means)... I really dont't know what this regex means... I know just a little about regex.

Comment: I really want to know what this expression means. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n
```

Don't print unless told to.

```
'/^>/!{H;$!b};
```

If the line doesn't begin with '>', add the line to the hold space and then if it isn't the last line of the file, jump to the end of the script (i.e. start over with the next line).

```
s/$/ /;
```

Add a blank space to the end of the line.

```
x;
```

Swap the line with the contents of the hold space.

```
1b;
```

If we're working on the first line (i.e. if this is the first time through the script) then jump to the end of the script.

```
s/\n//g;
```

Remove all line feeds (`\n`) from the the thing we're working on. That is, if it is several lines (from the hold space), turn them into one line.

```
p'
```

Print it.